# Overwride Initialize Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I create a class, I want to be able to override the initialize class. But it doesn't seem to work. Even tried using `: base()` to no avail.

```
public class Class1{
   public string Str1;
   public string Str2;

   public Class1(){ Str1 = "Hello"; }

   public Class1(string s) : base() <-------- Doesn't work
   {
        Str2 = "Goodbye";
   }
}
```

Basically I would like to call `new Class1("test");` and it should populate `Str1` with `Hello` and `Str2` with `test`, without having to rewrite the code int he first initializer to the second one.

What can be done to achieve this?

I can separate the initializer method into its own method and call them separately, but it just seems too redundant... Isn't there a direct way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
public Class1(string s) : base()
```

with

```
public Class1(string s) : this()
```

to call the parameterless constructor of the same class. `this()` = `Class1()`

---

Here is a example for a "`base()`-case" with inheritance

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Str1;
    public Class1() { Str1 = "Hello"; }
    public Class1(string s) { Str1 = s; }
}

public class Class2 : Class1
{
    public string Str2;
    public Class2() { Str2 = "World"; }
    public Class2(string s)  : base(s) // calls Class1(string s)
    {
        Str2 = s;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
Class2 c1 = new Class2("test"); // test test
Class2 c2 = new Class2(); //Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

`base` is to be used when you have a base class. 
`this` to be used in the same class.

Since you are calling the constructor in the same class, you should be using `this` instead of `base`;

Supplementing the above with some examples:

Say we have a base class, then you could use the `base` keyword like below.
**Note**: Base class constructor will be called first and then the child class constructor

```
public class MainClass
{
    public string Str1;

    public MainClass(string s)
    {
        Str1 = s;
    }
}

public class Class1 : MainClass
{
    public string Str2;

    public Class1(string s) : base("Hello")
    {
        Str2 = "Goodbye";
    }
}
```

Invocation: `var myClass =  new Class1("GoodBye");`

---

Doing the same in the same `class`:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Str1;
    public string Str2;

    public Class1(string s)
    {
        Str2 = "Goodbye";
        Str1 = "Hello";
    }
}
```

OR by calling the `default constructor`:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Str1;
    public string Str2;

    public Class1()
    {
        Str1 = "Hello";
    }

    public Class1(string s): this()
    {
        Str2 = "Goodbye";
    }
}
```

**Note**: The `default constructor` would be called first here

Invocation: `var class1 =  new Class1("GoodBye");`

---

Another way is to use `Auto-Implemented` properties as in mentioned code the `property` is given a default value:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Str1 { get; set; } = "Hello";
    public string Str2 { get; set; }

    public Class1(string s)
    {
        Str2 = "Goodbye";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 'base':

```
public Class1(string s) : base()
{...}
```

Use 'this':

```
public Class1(string s) : this()
{...}
```

Or if your intention is to always assign a static value to 'Str1' save yourself the trouble of invoking the first constructor by simply assigning the value directly to the property:

```
public string Str1 = "Hello";
```